# SageMaker RCF Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-sagemaker

I have a DynamoDB table filled with nice data. I use Datapipeline to extract this to S3 and it generates a folder with 3 files.

1) "139xx-x911-407x-83xx-06x5x659xx16" that contains all DB data in this format:

```
{"TimeStamp":{"s":"1539699960"},"SystemID":{"n":"1001"},"AccMin":{"n":"497"},"AccMax":{"n":"509"},"CustomerID":{"n":"10001"},"SensorID":{"n":"101"}}
```

2) "manifest"

```
{"name":"DynamoDB-export","version":3,
entries: [
{"url":"s3://cxxxx/2018-10-18-15-25-02/139xx-x911-407x-83xx-06x5x659xx16","mandatory":true}
]}
```

3) "_SUCCESS" No data inside.

I then go to SageMaker -> Training Jobs -> Create Training Job. Here I fill in everything to create a Random Cut Forest model, and point it towards the above data (I have tried both manifest file and the bigger data-file.
The training fails with error:

> "ClientError: No data was found. Please make sure training data is
>   provided."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your interest in SageMaker.

The manifest is optional, but if provided it should conform to the schema described at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_S3DataSource.html . Also, RandomCutForest does not support input data in JSON format. Only protobuf and CSV are supported, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/randomcutforest.html

In order to get training working you have to convert input data to CSV or protobuf format and set content_type value appropriately. If you want to use a manifest file, then S3 location should point to that file and context has to be fixed to conform the schema. You can however remove the manifest and point S3 location to s3://bucket/path/to/data/.

I hope this helps.

Regards,
Yury